# Do you have any real example of Data Science reports?

Tags: usecase

I recently found this use cases on Kaggle for Data Science and Data Analytics.

[Data Science Use Cases](https://www.kaggle.com/wiki/DataScienceUseCases)

However, I am curious to find examples and case studies of real reports from other professionals in some of those use cases on the link. Including hypothesis, testing, reports, conclusions (and maybe also the datasets they have used)

Do you have any kind of those reports to share?

I am aware of the difficulty to share this kind of details and this is why it is not a Google-search-and-find answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can better go through various university thesis reports and data science related journal papers to get more details on "Including hypothesis, testing, reports, conclusions" of the above mentioned Data science related problems.

Check these links from Stanford university :

http://cs229.stanford.edu/projects2014.html

http://cs229.stanford.edu/projects2013.html

http://cs229.stanford.edu/projects2012.html

Answer (score 0):

There are some reports [available on Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/kernels?sortBy=voteCount&group=everyone&search=report&page=1&pageSize=20&turbolinks%5BrestorationIdentifier%5D=99394e99-8570-4410-945b-aec8606e9732) using their kernels. [This link](https://www.kaggle.com/kernels?sortBy=voteCount&group=everyone&search=report&page=1&pageSize=20&turbolinks%5BrestorationIdentifier%5D=99394e99-8570-4410-945b-aec8606e9732) searches for "reports" among all the public kernels, and some of the reports even have good criticisms.